# Calculate Weighted Standard Deviation?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want my network to calculate the weighted standard deviation (or variance) on the fly while training.

The weights must come from a constant vector, something like:

```
weights = np.array([0.1,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.1,0.3,0.6,0.9])
```

The input is of the same size as `weights`.

How can I do this in Keras?

I've arrived at a formula for the mean

```
weights = K.variable(weights)
width = dot([in, weights],axes=-1, normalize=False)
```

but even this crashes with an error:

```
File "/sps/atlas/a/aghosh/miniconda3/envs/cpuApril19/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/layers/merge.py", line 668, in dot
return Dot(axes=axes, normalize=normalize, **kwargs)(inputs)
File "~/envs/cpuApril19/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 474, in __call__
output_shape = self.compute_output_shape(input_shape)
File "~/envs/cpuApril19/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/layers/merge.py", line 512, in compute_output_shape
shape2.pop(0)
IndexError: pop from empty list
```

Edit:

I made a mistake, I would like to calculate the variance of the constant vector with the input as the weights.

Following @Sharky's suggestion I did:

```
constVector = np.array([-0.1,-0.4,-0.5,0.6,0.1,0.3,0.6,0.9])
....
in = Input(shape=(8,), name='Input')
width = Lambda(lambda x: tf.nn.weighted_moments(x,axes=-1,frequency_weights=in)[1])(constVector)
Model = Model(inputs=[in], outputs= width)
```

it gives this error:
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'

If I switch the tensors as :

```
tf.nn.weighted_moments(x,axes=-1,frequency_weights=constVector)[1])(in )
```

it compiles but I need to variance of `constVector` weighted by `in`

Edit2:
Just needed to implement the Lamda layer correctly

```
tf.nn.weighted_moments(constVector,axes=-1,frequency_weights=x)[1])(in)
```

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/moments

Comment: @Sharky useful but I need weighted moments

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/weighted_moments

Comment: your suggestion works! But I realised I need to switch the weights with the input to get what I want to compute. And then it doesn't work (see edit)

Comment: Ok got it working

Comment: Glad to hear. You can answer your own question, your earned an upvote(a powerful one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Sharky's comment I used TensorFlow's `weighted_moments()` function by wrapping it in Keras:

```
constVector = np.array([-0.1,-0.4,-0.5,0.6,0.1,0.3,0.6,0.9])
constVector = K.variable(constVector)
def wWidthFunc(x, y=constVector):
    # only works for 1-D vector inputs
    z = tf.nn.weighted_moments(y,axes=[1],frequency_weights=x)[1]
    z = K.expand_dims(z, -1)        # z of shape (batch_size, 1)
    return z
def make_width_model():
    m_input = Input(shape=(8,), name='Input_')
    width = Lambda(wWidthFunc)(m_input) # m_input values must be >0
    M_w = Model(inputs=[m_input], outputs= width)
    return M_w
```